# How to display animation first and then alert

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a code to create a toggle button now i created a javascript to popup an alert when clicked but it shows the alert first and then toggles the button. I want it to toggle first and then show the alert. I even tried setTimeout() of 3 sec but it is also not working

HTML:

```
<div class="buttonsArea">
            <div class="display" >
                 <label class="label toggle">
                      Appliance 1
                     <input type="checkbox" class="toggle_input" />
                     <div class="toggle-control" id="button1" onclick="alert(this)"></div>
                 </label>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin:auto;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;

}

.heading {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border:3px solid #8AC007;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.buttonsArea {
  padding-top:15%;
  width:150px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.display {
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.toggle .toggle-control {
  /*For Color transition effect*/
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.98, 0.99, 1, 0.99);
          transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.98, 0.99, 1, 0.99);

  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  display: inline-block; /* changed */
  border: 2px solid #8E8E93;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  position: relative;
  vertical-align:middle; /* new; can be removed if desired */
}
.toggle .toggle-control:after {
  /*For Marker transition effect*/
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.98, 0.99, 1, 0.99);
          transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.98, 0.99, 1, 0.99);
  content: "";
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.toggle input {
  display: none;
}
.toggle input:checked + .toggle-control {
  border-color: #4cd964;
  background-color: #4cd964;
}
.toggle input:checked + .toggle-control:after {
  left: 2em;
}
```

JS:

```
function myFunction(contents) {
     setTimeout(function(){ alert("Clicked on"); }, 3000);
}
```

Plzzz help!!!

Comment: You don't get any alert?

Comment: I get an alert. But i want alert to popup after the button is toggled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have two events

1. Click on div#button1 OR Click on checkbox
2. Checkbox value changed

You want to alert to display after the checkbox value changed (2nd event) but you're tying it to the first event. I suggest the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" class="toggle_input" onchange="alert(this)" />
```

This way, no matter how the checkbox value changes, you will get the result you want. You can also put a label in your  to change the value of the checkbox:

```
<div class="toggle-control" id="button1"><label for="cb">Click Me</label></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function `myFunction(contents)` is never being called. `div#button1`'s `onclick` is `alert(this)` when I think you want `onclick="myFunction(this)"`.

I'd also like to recommend that you rename function `myFunction` to a name more describing of its behaviour.

Comment: @user3398648 If I have answered your question, please accept my answer by clicking on the tick to the left. This is to show that further answers are not welcome and the problem is solved. You will earn reputation for this. Comments such as yours, along the lines of 'thanks' are not required here.

Answer (score 0):

Your function never triggers. You need to call the function too. If you're using jQuery, try something like

```
$('.toggle-control').click(function(){
   alert('Clicked'); 
}
```